# SQL percentile calculation running very slowly - need help speeding it up

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, database-performance

I have a large table (about 850 million rows for now) and need to calculate percentile values weekly as new data is inserted an the statics become dirty. However, that process is super slow (5-6 hours with my hardware/current query).

**How can I change my query to speed up the query?**

Right now, my query is basically this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [ident1]
    ,[ident2]
    ,[ident3]
    ,[ident4]
    ,percentile_cont(0.05)
        WITHIN GROUP (
            ORDER BY [value] ASC
        ) OVER (
            PARTITION BY [ident1]
                ,[ident2]
                ,[ident3]
                ,[ident4]
        ) AS [percentile_5]
    ,percentile_cont(0.10)
        WITHIN GROUP (
            ORDER BY [value] ASC
        ) OVER (
            PARTITION BY [ident1]
                ,[ident2]
                ,[ident3]
                ,[ident4]
        ) AS [percentile_10]
    ,percentile_cont(0.25)
        WITHIN GROUP (
            ORDER BY [value] ASC
        ) OVER (
            PARTITION BY [ident1]
                ,[ident2]
                ,[ident3]
                ,[ident4]
        ) AS [percentile_25]
    ,percentile_cont(0.50)
        WITHIN GROUP (
            ORDER BY [value] ASC
        ) OVER (
            PARTITION BY [ident1]
                ,[ident2]
                ,[ident3]
                ,[ident4]
        ) AS [percentile_50]
    ,percentile_cont(0.75)
        WITHIN GROUP (
            ORDER BY [value] ASC
        ) OVER (
            PARTITION BY [ident1]
                ,[ident2]
                ,[ident3]
                ,[ident4]
        ) AS [percentile_75]
    ,percentile_cont(0.90)
        WITHIN GROUP (
            ORDER BY [value] ASC
        ) OVER (
            PARTITION BY [ident1]
                ,[ident2]
                ,[ident3]
                ,[ident4]
        ) AS [percentile_90]
    ,percentile_cont(0.95)
        WITHIN GROUP (
            ORDER BY [value] ASC
        ) OVER (
            PARTITION BY [ident1]
                ,[ident2]
                ,[ident3]
                ,[ident4]
        ) AS [percentile_95]
FROM dataTable
```

I *think* that part of the issue is that with out the `DISTINCT` selection I'm getting a row every value in the DB. Is SQL smart enough to calculate the percentiles only once for each group? Or is it calculating repeatedly for each value?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you need percentile_**cont** or is it ok to use percentile_**disc**?

Comment: What does an execution plan tell you about this query? (The first place to look should be an execution plan.)  It may identify a missing index for example.

Comment: I'm working on getting the execution plan. My DBA has that feature disabled at the moment. In the meantime, what's the best way to index this? Clustered index on [ident1], [ident2], [ident3], [ident4], and [value]? Or perhaps some subset of the columns?

Answer (score 0):

Put the distinct in a subquery:

```
select . . .
from (select distinct . . . ) s;
```

`distinct` should be happening *after* all the `select` columns have been calculated.

Comment: This will not change the execution plan, Windowed Aggregates are calculated *before* `distinct`

Comment: @dnoeth . . . Exactly.  If there are 100 copies of a given row, they get calculated 100 times.  Presumably the OP wants the windowed function values after the distinct is applied.

Comment: But a percentile is usually calculated on the full data set, applying DISTINCT beforehand might change the result.

Comment: @dnoeth . . . I find very few instances where I use `select distinct` and none where there are window functions.  I can only vaguely guess what the OP might really want.

Comment: SQL Server only implements the Window version, but the OP wants the Aggregate version `percentile_cont(0.05)
        WITHIN GROUP (
            ORDER BY [value] ASC
        ) ... GROUP BY [ident1]
                ,[ident2]
                ,[ident3]
                ,[ident4]`

Comment: @dnoeth . . . Duh!  That makes a lot of sense.